# How do I find duplicate/overlap times and days in my opening hour table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have an table contains different shops business hour

```
ID  ShopID  OpeningTime ClosingTime DayID   DayDescription
1   20010   09:00   17:00   1   Monday
2   20010   09:00   17:00   2   Tuesday
3   20010   09:00   17:00   3   Wednesday
4   20010   09:00   17:00   4   Thursday
5   20010   09:00   17:00   5   Friday
6   20010   09:00   17:00   8   Weekday
7   30151   09:00   12:00   1   Monday
8   30151   13:00   17:00   1   Monday
9   30151   09:00   12:00   2   Tuesday
10  30151   13:00   17:00   2   Tuesday
11  30151   09:00   12:00   3   Wednesday
12  30151   13:00   17:00   3   Wednesday
13  30151   09:00   12:00   4   Thursday
14  30151   13:00   17:00   4   Thursday
15  30151   09:00   12:00   5   Friday
16  30151   13:00   17:00   5   Friday
17  30151   09:00   17:00   8   Weekday
18  40265   08:00   21:00   1   Monday
19  40265   08:00   21:00   2   Tuesday
20  40265   08:00   21:00   3   Wednesday
21  40265   08:00   21:00   4   Thursday
22  40265   08:00   17:00   5   Friday
23  40265   08:00   21:00   8   Weekday
24  50541   09:00   17:00   2   Tuesday
25  50541   09:00   17:00   3   Wednesday
26  50541   09:00   17:00   8   Weekday
27  65892   09:00   17:00   1   Monday
28  65892   09:00   17:00   2   Tuesday
29  65892   09:00   17:00   3   Wednesday
30  65892   09:00   17:00   4   Thursday
31  65892   09:00   17:00   5   Friday
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ChIW.jpg) is the table.

I want to use sql queries to get these results:

1. Hours of Monday -Friday (DayID 1,2,3,4,5) are the same and they are also the same as weekday (dayID = 8), eg : shopID 20010
2. Hours of Monday -Friday are the same, but is different from weekday, eg : shopID 30151
3. Hours of Monday -Friday are different, and weekday has value, eg:shopID 40265
4. Not open for all 5 days(Monday -Friday),but weekday has value, eg:shopID 50541
5. Open for all 5 days(Monday -Friday) at the same time, but does not have weekday record, eg: ShopID 65892

Can anyone please help with SQL statement to get corporate results?
And do I miss any anomalies scenario?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your data as text.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2014

Comment: That's too broad. Actually you have 5 questions.

Comment: That question is too broad. Did you try something?